# How do you generate lists of letters in R that follow a repetition pattern?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am looking to generate multiple, random lists of letters in which letters in a certain position repeat.

Here is an example of the "2-back" rule. It is a list of random letters, but 25% of the time the letter matches the letter that came 2 before it. The ones that match are 1 and the ones that do not are 0

```
R  0
Y  0
M  0
Y  1
L  0
C  0
F  0 
G  0
S  0
G  1
```

I want to be able to specify the length of the list as well as the percentage of letters that do actually follow the pattern and repeat. The rest of the letters would be randomly generated.

I don't know if I have explained the problem well. Can someone potentially help me with this?

Comment: it's not clear to me what your pattern is - could you expand please?

Comment: Not clear to me what is the rule.

Comment: Here is an example of the "2-back" rule. It is a list of random letters, but 25% of the time the letter matches the letter that came 2 before it. The ones that match are 1 and the ones that do not are 0

R  0
Y  0
M  0
Y 1
L 0
C 0
F 0 
G 0
S 0
G 1

Answer (score 1):

Since this process is state dependent I think this might be a rare case where it's OK to use a `for`/`while` loop, which is normally very slow compared to the alternatives. You still want to pre-allocate the vectors by creating them at their total length to start with. You can do something like:

```
total_length = 20
back_prob = 0.25
two_back_seq = character(total_length)
types = character(total_length)

# Generate the random results used to determine if we sample randomly
#   or repeat the 2-back element
rolls = runif(total_length)

current_index = 1
while (current_index <= total_length) {
   if ((rolls[current_index] > back_prob) || (current_index < 3)) {
       two_back_seq[current_index] = sample(letters, 1)
       types[current_index] = "random"
   } else {
       two_back_seq[current_index] = two_back_seq[current_index - 2]
       types[current_index] = "two back"
   }
   current_index = current_index + 1
}
```

An example result:

```
> two_back_seq
 [1] "u" "x" "u" "b" "x" "w" "t" "w" "o" "b" "o" "l" "m" "m" "m" "u" "d" "t" "k" "t"
> types
 [1] "random"   "random"   "two back" "random"   "random"   "random"  
 "random"   "two back" "random"   "random"   "two back" "random"   "random"  
[14] "random"   "two back" "random"   "random"   "random"   "random"   "random"
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to make the pattern for a single letter, `a`. Start by generating some letters, using `prob` to set the relative frequencies of the letters:

`x <- sample(letters[1:5], 500, prob=c(.01,.09,.2,.3,.3), replace=TRUE)`

Now insert extra letters to make the pattern at intervals:

`x <- ifelse(x[-1:-3]=="a", "a", x[seq(1,length(x)-3)])`

Does that help?

(To check which elements are equal to `a` I used `which(x == "a")`)

Comment: Now that you've changed your questions a little, if you want the doubling to itself random (e.g., only 25% of cases double back) try `ifelse(x[-1:-3]=="a" & runif(length(x)-3)<.25, "a", x[seq(1,length(x)-3)])` instead.